# Unable to extend ListFragment - "Call requires API level 11"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to extend ListFragment, but I keep getting the error stated above. I added the android support library to my project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You probably have the wrong import on your project/class.
You probably extending ListFragment from the API 11 (android.app.ListFragment)
and you should extend ListFragment from the compatibility class (`android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`)

Answer (score 7):

Try adding

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
```